# UDP broadcast and automatic server discovery in python, TCP socket unavailable

Tags: python, sockets, networking, broadcast

I'm developing a reverse shell application in python, and right now I'm trying to implement an autodiscovery feature. It should work as follows:

1. The server broadcasts the IP/port it listens for connections on, and waits for a client. If no client tries to connect in a few seconds, it broadcasts again (and repeat till a connection).
2. The client tries to receive the broadcast of the server, and connects to the advertised IP/port.

The broadcast works fine, the client receives the IP/port and successfully connects, however after using the connected pair of ports I get (server side):

> socket.error: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

Server side test code:

```
sckt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sckt.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sckt.settimeout(2)
sckt.bind(('', 9999))
sckt.listen(5)

broadcastSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
broadcastSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
broadcastSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
while True:
    broadcastSocket.sendto(socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()) + ' ' + str(9999), ('<broadcast>', 8888))
    try:
        sock, address = sckt.accept()
        break
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
broadcastSocket.close()
sckt.settimeout(None)

sock.send('test')
# if I add time.sleep(1) here, it works, but I don't get why
# would sock be unavailable at first, but available a second later
print sock.recv(1) # this is where it fails
# note that it also fails with any recv buffer size, for instance 1024
```

Why on earth would I want to receive 1 byte of data, you might ask. I have an algorithm which prefixes messages with their lengths, and the receiver reads this prefix byte-by-byte till a delimiter, thats why.
Client side test code:

```
broadcastSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
broadcastSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
broadcastSocket.settimeout(3)
broadcastSocket.bind(('', 8888))
while True:
    try:
        data = broadcastSocket.recv(1024)
        break
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
broadcastSocket.close()

sckt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sckt.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sckt.connect((str(data.split()[0]), int(data.split()[1])))

print sckt.recv(1024)
sckt.send('lel')
```

If I omit the whole broadcast and autodiscovery part of the code and simply manually enter the IP/port of the server `print sock.recv(1)` doesn't fail.
Any clues on what the issue might be?

Comment: It works. Your code should add, `send` and `recv` calls producing the error

Comment: I added a few lines of code which triggers the error.

Comment: It is now clear. In any case you may want to change the title, because your real problem is with the TCP socket. Something along the lines of "TCP socket dies before receiving data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `sckt.settimeout(None)` to `sock.settimout(None)` in the server code.

You want to have the **accepted** socket in blocking mode and not the **accepting** one.

This ensures that the `sckt.recv` waits for an incoming message from the client.

P.S.
`sock.setblocking(1)` is exactly the same

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Wasted like 3 hours with this nasty error. For some weird reason I thought that the accepted socket inherits the blocking property of the accepting one, but clearly that is not the case. But still, this is true to some degree as accepted sockets are usually blocking by default, but now it was unblocking (and I guess it's because the accepting socket was unblocking).

Comment: You are setting the **accepting** socket in non-blocking mode at the beginning of your code with `sckt.settimeout(2)`. That's why you get a **non-blocking accepted** socket.